# Network programming in Go

Tags: go

I'm studying Go for network programming. The problem is Go documentation is too simple. For example， I don't know when to use `net.DialTCP`, and when to use `TCPListener` object to `AcceptTCP`, what's the difference? How about client communicate with another client? Not client to server.

Comment: Check out the ["Network programming with Go"](http://jan.newmarch.name/go/) free e-book.

Comment: @kostix e-book has great examples and pretty thorough. I refer to it often.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Connecting

In Go, you use the `Dial` function from `net` to connect to a remote machine.

```
net.Dial("tcp","google.com:80")
net.Dial("udp","tracker.thepiratebay.org:6969")
net.Dial("ip","kremvax.su")
net.Dial("unix","/dev/log")
```

This gives you an abstract `Conn` object that represents the connection you just established. `Conn` implements the `ReadWriteCloser` interface from `io` and a couple of other functions. You can use this object to send and receive data.

## Listening

To listen, i.e. open a port, you use the `Listen` function from net. Calling `Listen` gives you a `Listener` object. Use `Accept` to accept incoming connections. `Accept` returns another `Conn` object that can be used as above.

```
ls, err := net.Listen("tcp",":1337")
if err != nil {
    // port probably blocked, insert error handling here
}

conn, err := ls.Accept()
if err != nil {
    // error handling
}

conn.Write("Hello, world!")
```

## DialTCP and ListenTCP

These functions give you more control over TCP connections. I suggest you to only use them if they are definitly needed for your program as `Dial` and `Listen` are simpler, more generic and easily allow you to adapt your program to other types of network connections.

Answer (score 2):

`net.DialTCP` is used on the client side to create a connection to remote server.

`net.TCPListener.AcceptTCP` is used on the server side to accept new connection (possibly initiated by `net.DialTCP` if client is written in Go). Note that listener may accept multiple connections, one by one, thus serving multiple clients at once (e.g. each in different goroutine).

Depending on whether you are writing client or server, you use `net.DialTCP` or `net.TCPListener`

Maybe you should learn about network programming in general first? Then these would make more sense I think.

Comment: So if one client communicate with another client ( Not a client-Server pattern), I can use net.DialTCP?

Comment: @Pole_Zhang You always have one side that listens and one that connects when you use network. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Pole_Zhang I'd suggest you to read an introductio to network programming before you proceed.